# j2me application

Tags: image-capture

Im writing a j2me application for mobile...im trying to open the mobile camera in the application and capture the image..how to do it?please reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If the MMAPI is supported by the phone, you could take snapshots like this.

```
//Use this method to initialize
// m_Form is the displayed Form
private void startPlayer() {
   try {
         Player m_objPlayer = Manager.createPlayer("capture://video");
         m_objPlayer.realize();
         m_objVideoControl = (VideoControl)
         m_objPlayer.getControl("VideoControl");
         if (m_objVideoControl != null) 
         {
           m_Form.append((Item) m_objVideoControl.initDisplayMode(
           VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, null));
           m_objPlayer.start();
         }
       } catch (Exception exc) {
            // handle Exception
}

// Use this to take a snapshot
public void commandAction(Command cmd, Displayable d) {
   if ((cmd == snapShotCommand) && d == this) {
    try {
         data =
           m_objVideoControl.getSnapshot("encoding=jpeg&width =160&height=120"));
          // m_objVideoControl.getSnapshot("encoding=png&width= 80&height=60"));
          // m_objVideoControl.getSnapshot("encoding=bmp&width= 160&height=120"));
   } catch (Exception exc) {
     // handle Exception
   }
}
```

Here is an old article on sun [click me!](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/picture/)